# Query JIRA Story Point HISTORY

Tags: jira, points, jql, user-stories

We used JIRA on-demand to manage an Agile project. Sometimes a story may be preliminarily sized in story points, but is then re-sized before commitment. I would like a query which shows the history of each story's status and point value.

For example:

```
Story 99 history:
1/1/2014 -- Status = Open; Points = Null
1/15/2014 -- Status = Reviewed; Points = 5
2/15/2014 -- Status = Committed; Points = 8
```

My goal (and maybe there is another way to do this) is to see how often we change our story sizes.

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried Google.

I've looked for answers on Atlassian forum.

I've tried WAS and CHANGED.

I have no idea how to do this. I am not a Jira expert or developer.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had a solution for you in using the "changed" JQL query (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-WAS), but unfortunately it looks like that is not supported currently in Jira.  I received the following error from our hosted Jira instance:

History searches do not support the 'Story Points' field.

So as a user on demand query I don't think it is currently possible.

The only way I see of doing this would be to have a set day/time where you would run a query to get the current story points, export it as an excel file and then do it again after you review a set of stories and write some excel functions to show the change.

The larger question would be around your agile/scrum processes as to why estimated would change so frequently as to need tracking.   If the team as a whole decides the points its ok if it doesn't match the reality once we start working on it.  Or is this a case where it is updated on more than one occasion before its actually being worked on?  If thats the case then I'd say that the story isn't well defined and need more information before it can be estimated?

Comment: If you're still wondering 'why?', while I can't speak for the OP, I will say, I'm trying to setup a query to monitor when somebody other than the team sets or changes the point count.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Michael's answer, the daily monitoring for a given set of results to a query can be semi-automated using a JIRA filter subscription. You will still need to extract the issues from the results manually but at least in principle you can be sure not to miss any resizing that happens.